# How to get paths to dependencies in Gradle cache?

Tags: gradle

I can get a list of dependencies with `gradlew dependencies --configuration runtime`. Is there a command-line way to have it emit the file system paths of the dependencies in the Gradle cache?

Alternatively, what I really want to output is a usable classpath generated from the dependencies. Is there a way to get that from the `dependencies` command? Something like what the following outputs but without having to go through the motions of creating a task:

```
task classpath << {
    println configurations.runtime.asPath
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to output a class path, a task like the above is the best solution. Note that the Gradle dependency cache is an internal data structure and you shouldn't make any assumptions about its layout (which may change between versions).